# Make A Scrolling Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I have been having trouble getting a scrolling background on my site. I have tried a bunch off different methods and StackOverflow topics and I can't get it to work. Basically, I have a background and I need it to keep looping. Please help. Thanks!

This is not the same as the linked question, because I tried that and I didn't work for me, and the method provided is a different method.

Comment: First of all, you please go read [ask] - also “asap”.

Comment: @sp0ng3w0rthy - I tried that and a few other methods, and they didn't work. That's why I opened this - BTW your method worked great :D (I would have up voted it if it would have let me)

Comment: @noah Oh sorry for that then bub, nice to hear it worked out eventually, next time try stating more about your question in order to avoid incorrect duplicate markings :)

Comment: @sp0ng3w0rthy - Sounds good, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is quite vague, I believe [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) would assist you, look into the `background-repeat` property.